# After upgrade from 2.3.4 to 2.3.5 got compilation error with module

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, setup-di-compile

I am trying couple of hours to figure out what is wrong with this constructor and have no idea

```
namespace Aitoc\ProductFileAttachments\Block\Product;

use Aitoc\ProductFileAttachments\Model\ResourceModel\Attachments\CollectionFactory as AttachmentsCollectionFactory;
use Aitoc\ProductFileAttachments\Helper\Data;
use Aitoc\ProductFileAttachments\Model\ResourceModel\Icons\CollectionFactory as IconsCollectionFactory;
use Aitoc\ProductFileAttachments\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory as OrderCollectionFactory;
use Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context as ContextHttp;
use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder;
use Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule;
use Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions;
use Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Aitoc\ProductFileAttachments\Model\ResourceModel\AttachmentAttributes\Collection as AttachmentAttributesCollection;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Attachments extends ProductsList
{
    /**
     * Global setting
     */
    const DISPLAY_IF_ORDERED = 'product_file_attachments/general_settings/display_if_ordered';

    /**
     * @var AttachmentsCollectionFactory
     */
    private $attachmentsCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    private $helper;

    /**
     * @var SessionFactory
     */
    private $customerSessionFactory;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resource;

    /**
     * @var OrderCollectionFactory
     */
    private $orderCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var IconsCollectionFactory
     */
    private $iconsCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @var AttachmentAttributesCollection
     */
    private $attachmentAttributesCollection;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;
    
    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param ContextHttp $httpContext
     * @param Builder $sqlBuilder
     * @param Rule $rule
     * @param Conditions $conditionsHelper
     * @param attachmentAttributesCollection $attachmentAttributesCollection
     * @param AttachmentsCollectionFactory $attachmentsCollectionFactory
     * @param SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory
     * @param OrderCollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
     * @param ResourceConnection $resource
     * @param IconsCollectionFactory $iconsCollectionFactory
     * @param Data $helper
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        ContextHttp $httpContext,
        Builder $sqlBuilder,
        Rule $rule,
        Conditions $conditionsHelper,
        AttachmentAttributesCollection $attachmentAttributesCollection,
        AttachmentsCollectionFactory $attachmentsCollectionFactory,
        SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory,
        OrderCollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        IconsCollectionFactory $iconsCollectionFactory,
        Data $helper,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->attachmentsCollectionFactory = $attachmentsCollectionFactory;
        $this->registry = $context->getRegistry();
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->attachmentAttributesCollection = $attachmentAttributesCollection;
        $this->customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->iconsCollectionFactory = $iconsCollectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $productCollectionFactory, $catalogProductVisibility, $httpContext, $sqlBuilder, $rule, $conditionsHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Disable attachment block cache
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addData(
            [
                'cache_lifetime' => false,
                'cache_tags' => ['Attachments'],
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function createCollection()
    {
        $currentProduct = $this->registry->registry('product');
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
        if ($currentProduct) {
            $productId = $currentProduct->getId();
            $attachmentsCollection = $this->attachmentsCollectionFactory->create();
            $attachmentsCollection->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId);
            $attachmentsArray = [];
            foreach ($attachmentsCollection as $attachmentItem) {
                $attachmentId = $attachmentItem->getId();
                $attachmentAttributesCollection = $this->attachmentAttributesCollection;
                $attachmentAttributesCollection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
                $attachmentAttributesCollection->addFieldToFilter('file_id', $attachmentId);
                if ($storeId != '0') {
                    $attachmentAttributesCollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['eq' => $storeId]);
                    if (count($attachmentAttributesCollection->getAllIds()) == 0) {
                        $attachmentAttributesCollection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
                        $attachmentAttributesCollection->addFieldToFilter('file_id', $attachmentId);
                        $attachmentAttributesCollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['eq' => '0']);
                    }
                } else {
                    $attachmentAttributesCollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', ['eq' => '0']);
                }
                foreach ($attachmentAttributesCollection as $item) {
                    $attributeId = $item->getId();
                    $itemVisible = $item->getVisible();
                    $itemIsOrdered = $item->getIsOrdered();
                    $itemExpansion  = pathinfo($attachmentItem->getFile());
                    if (array_key_exists('extension', $itemExpansion)) {
                        $itemExpansion = $itemExpansion['extension'];
                    } else {
                        $itemExpansion = 'link';
                    }
                    if ($itemVisible) {
                        $iconItem = $this->getIconByExpansion($itemExpansion);
                        $attachmentsArray = $this->checkVisibility($iconItem, $item, $itemIsOrdered, $productId, $attachmentsArray, $attachmentId, $attributeId);
                    }
                }
            }

            return $attachmentsArray;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param int $productId
     * @param int $currentCustomerId
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isProductOrdered($productId, $currentCustomerId)
    {
        $salesOrdersCollection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
        $salesOrdersCollection->isOrdered();
        $salesOrdersCollection->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $currentCustomerId);

        return (bool)$salesOrdersCollection->load()->count();
    }

    /**
     * @param array $iconItem
     * @param AttachmentsCollectionFactory $item
     * @param bool $itemIsOrdered
     * @param int $productId
     * @param array $attachmentsArray
     * @return array
     */
    public function checkVisibility($iconItem, $item, $itemIsOrdered, $productId, $attachmentsArray, $attachmentId, $attributeId)
    {
        $needCustomerGroupIds = $this->helper->getCustomerGroupValidation($attributeId);
        $customerSession = $this->customerSessionFactory->create();
        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $currentCustomerGroup = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
            $currentCustomerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
        } else {
            $currentCustomerGroup = '0';
            $currentCustomerId = '0';
        }
        if (count($needCustomerGroupIds) && in_array($currentCustomerGroup, $needCustomerGroupIds)) {
            $globalIsOrdered = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::DISPLAY_IF_ORDERED, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE) ?: [];
            if ($itemIsOrdered || $globalIsOrdered) {
                $isOrdered = $this->isProductOrdered($productId, $currentCustomerId);
                if ($isOrdered) {
                    $attachmentsArray[$attachmentId] = $item->getData();
                }
            } else {
                $attachmentsArray[$attachmentId] = $item->getData();
            }
        }
        if (array_key_exists($attachmentId, $attachmentsArray)) {
            $attachmentsArray[$attachmentId]['icon'] = $iconItem;
        }
        return $attachmentsArray;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $itemExpansion
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIconByExpansion($itemExpansion)
    {
        $iconsCollection = $this->iconsCollectionFactory->create();
        $iconsCollection->addFieldToFilter('expansion', $itemExpansion);
        $iconsItems = $iconsCollection->getItems();
        if ($iconsItems) {
            foreach ($iconsItems as $iconItem) {
                $iconItem = $iconItem->getFile();
            }
        } else {
            $iconItem = '';
        }
        $iconsCollection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
        return $iconItem;
    }
}
```

The class it is extending: *vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Block/Product/ProductsList.php*

```
namespace Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\Html\Pager;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice;
use Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;
use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Combine;
use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Sql\Builder;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;
use Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions;

/**
 * Catalog Products List widget block
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
class ProductsList extends AbstractProduct implements BlockInterface, IdentityInterface
{
    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;

    /**
     * Name of request parameter for page number value
     *
     * @deprecated @see $this->getData('page_var_name')
     */
    const PAGE_VAR_NAME = 'np';

    /**
     * Default value for products per page
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE = 5;

    /**
     * Default value whether show pager or not
     */
    const DEFAULT_SHOW_PAGER = false;

    /**
     * Instance of pager block
     *
     * @var Pager
     */
    protected $pager;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var Visibility
     */
    protected $catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var Builder
     */
    protected $sqlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var Rule
     */
    protected $rule;

    /**
     * @var Conditions
     */
    protected $conditionsHelper;

    /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    private $priceCurrency;

    /**
     * Json Serializer Instance
     *
     * @var Json
     */
    private $json;

    /**
     * @var LayoutFactory
     */
    private $layoutFactory;

    /**
     * @var EncoderInterface|null
     */
    private $urlEncoder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList
     */
    private $rendererListBlock;

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param Visibility $catalogProductVisibility
     * @param Context $httpContext
     * @param Builder $sqlBuilder
     * @param Rule $rule
     * @param Conditions $conditionsHelper
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param array $data
     * @param Json|null $json
     * @param LayoutFactory|null $layoutFactory
     * @param EncoderInterface|null $urlEncoder
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        Context $httpContext,
        Builder $sqlBuilder,
        Rule $rule,
        Conditions $conditionsHelper,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        array $data = [],
        Json $json = null,
        LayoutFactory $layoutFactory = null,
        EncoderInterface $urlEncoder = null
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->sqlBuilder = $sqlBuilder;
        $this->rule = $rule;
        $this->conditionsHelper = $conditionsHelper;
        $this->json = $json ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Json::class);
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LayoutFactory::class);
        $this->urlEncoder = $urlEncoder ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(EncoderInterface::class);
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    }

    /**
     * Internal constructor, that is called from real constructor
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('empty', 6)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('1column', 5)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-left', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-right', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('3columns', 3);

        $this->addData(
            [
                'cache_lifetime' => 86400,
                'cache_tags' => [
                    Product::CACHE_TAG,
                ],
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.RequestAwareBlockMethod)
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $conditions = $this->getData('conditions')
            ? $this->getData('conditions')
            : $this->getData('conditions_encoded');

        return [
            'CATALOG_PRODUCTS_LIST_WIDGET',
            $this->getPriceCurrency()->getCurrency()->getCode(),
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            $this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId(),
            $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_GROUP),
            (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getData('page_var_name'), 1),
            $this->getProductsPerPage(),
            $this->getProductsCount(),
            $conditions,
            $this->json->serialize($this->getRequest()->getParams()),
            $this->getTemplate(),
            $this->getTitle()
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function getProductPriceHtml(
        Product $product,
        $priceType = null,
        $renderZone = \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
        array $arguments = []
    ) {
        if (!isset($arguments['zone'])) {
            $arguments['zone'] = $renderZone;
        }
        $arguments['price_id'] = isset($arguments['price_id'])
            ? $arguments['price_id']
            : 'old-price-' . $product->getId() . '-' . $priceType;
        $arguments['include_container'] = isset($arguments['include_container'])
            ? $arguments['include_container']
            : true;
        $arguments['display_minimal_price'] = isset($arguments['display_minimal_price'])
            ? $arguments['display_minimal_price']
            : true;

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $priceRender */
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
        if (!$priceRender) {
            $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
                'product.price.render.default',
                ['data' => ['price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices']]
            );
        }

        $price = $priceRender->render(
            FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            $arguments
        );

        return $price;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function getDetailsRendererList()
    {
        if (empty($this->rendererListBlock)) {
            /** @var $layout LayoutInterface */
            $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create(['cacheable' => false]);
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_widget_product_list')->load();
            $layout->generateXml();
            $layout->generateElements();

            $this->rendererListBlock = $layout->getBlock('category.product.type.widget.details.renderers');
        }
        return $this->rendererListBlock;
    }

    /**
     * Get post parameters.
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAddToCartPostParams(Product $product)
    {
        $url = $this->getAddToCartUrl($product);
        return [
            'action' => $url,
            'data' => [
                'product' => $product->getEntityId(),
                ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->urlEncoder->encode($url),
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->setProductCollection($this->createCollection());
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and return product collection
     *
     * @return Collection
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.RequestAwareBlockMethod)
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function createCollection()
    {
        /** @var $collection Collection */
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();

        if ($this->getData('store_id') !== null) {
            $collection->setStoreId($this->getData('store_id'));
        }

        $collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
            ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
            ->setCurPage($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getData('page_var_name'), 1));

        $conditions = $this->getConditions();
        $conditions->collectValidatedAttributes($collection);
        $this->sqlBuilder->attachConditionToCollection($collection, $conditions);

        /**
         * Prevent retrieval of duplicate records. This may occur when multiselect product attribute matches
         * several allowed values from condition simultaneously
         */
        $collection->distinct(true);

        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Update conditions if the category is an anchor category
     *
     * @param array $condition
     * @return array
     */
    private function updateAnchorCategoryConditions(array $condition): array
    {
        if (array_key_exists('value', $condition)) {
            $categoryId = $condition['value'];

            try {
                $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                return $condition;
            }

            $children = $category->getIsAnchor() ? $category->getChildren(true) : [];
            if ($children) {
                $children = explode(',', $children);
                $condition['operator'] = "()";
                $condition['value'] = array_merge([$categoryId], $children);
            }
        }

        return $condition;
    }

    /**
     * Get conditions
     *
     * @return Combine
     */
    protected function getConditions()
    {
        $conditions = $this->getData('conditions_encoded')
            ? $this->getData('conditions_encoded')
            : $this->getData('conditions');

        if ($conditions) {
            $conditions = $this->conditionsHelper->decode($conditions);
        }

        foreach ($conditions as $key => $condition) {
            if (!empty($condition['attribute'])) {
                if (in_array($condition['attribute'], ['special_from_date', 'special_to_date'])) {
                    $conditions[$key]['value'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($condition['value']));
                }

                if ($condition['attribute'] == 'category_ids') {
                    $conditions[$key] = $this->updateAnchorCategoryConditions($condition);
                }
            }
        }

        $this->rule->loadPost(['conditions' => $conditions]);
        return $this->rule->getConditions();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve how many products should be displayed
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if ($this->hasData('products_count')) {
            return $this->getData('products_count');
        }

        if (null === $this->getData('products_count')) {
            $this->setData('products_count', self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT);
        }

        return $this->getData('products_count');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve how many products should be displayed
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsPerPage()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('products_per_page')) {
            $this->setData('products_per_page', self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE);
        }
        return $this->getData('products_per_page');
    }

    /**
     * Return flag whether pager need to be shown or not
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function showPager()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('show_pager')) {
            $this->setData('show_pager', self::DEFAULT_SHOW_PAGER);
        }
        return (bool)$this->getData('show_pager');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve how many products should be displayed on page
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function getPageSize()
    {
        return $this->showPager() ? $this->getProductsPerPage() : $this->getProductsCount();
    }

    /**
     * Render pagination HTML
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        if ($this->showPager() && $this->getProductCollection()->getSize() > $this->getProductsPerPage()) {
            if (!$this->pager) {
                $this->pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    Pager::class,
                    $this->getWidgetPagerBlockName()
                );

                $this->pager->setUseContainer(true)
                    ->setShowAmounts(true)
                    ->setShowPerPage(false)
                    ->setPageVarName($this->getData('page_var_name'))
                    ->setLimit($this->getProductsPerPage())
                    ->setTotalLimit($this->getProductsCount())
                    ->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());
            }
            if ($this->pager instanceof \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock) {
                return $this->pager->toHtml();
            }
        }
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        $identities = [];
        if ($this->getProductCollection()) {
            foreach ($this->getProductCollection() as $product) {
                if ($product instanceof IdentityInterface) {
                    $identities += $product->getIdentities();
                }
            }
        }

        return $identities ?: [Product::CACHE_TAG];
    }

    /**
     * Get value of widgets' title parameter
     *
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->getData('title');
    }

    /**
     * Get currency of product
     *
     * @return PriceCurrencyInterface
     * @deprecated 100.2.0
     */
    private function getPriceCurrency()
    {
        if ($this->priceCurrency === null) {
            $this->priceCurrency = ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(PriceCurrencyInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->priceCurrency;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = [])
    {
        $requestingPageUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('requesting_page_url');

        if (!empty($requestingPageUrl)) {
            $additional['useUencPlaceholder'] = true;
            $url = parent::getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional);
            return str_replace('%25uenc%25', $this->urlEncoder->encode($requestingPageUrl), $url);
        }

        return parent::getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional);
    }

    /**
     * Get widget block name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getWidgetPagerBlockName()
    {
        $pageName = $this->getData('page_var_name');
        $pagerBlockName = 'widget.products.list.pager';

        if (!$pageName) {
            return $pagerBlockName;
        }

        return $pagerBlockName . '.' . $pageName;
    }
}
```

Every time I try to compile I get:

```
Interception cache generation... 6/8 [=====================>------]  75% 1 min 544.0 MiBErrors during compilation:
    Aitoc\ProductFileAttachments\Block\Product\Attachments
        Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface. Actual type: array; File: html/app/code/Aitoc/ProductFileAttachments/Block/Product/Attachments.php

Total Errors Count: 1
```

Comment: can you please share what error are you getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Change `__constractor()` in the file **Aitoc\ProductFileAttachments\Block\Product\Attachments.php**

From:

```
public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        ContextHttp $httpContext,
        Builder $sqlBuilder,
        Rule $rule,
        Conditions $conditionsHelper,
        AttachmentAttributesCollection $attachmentAttributesCollection,
        AttachmentsCollectionFactory $attachmentsCollectionFactory,
        SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory,
        OrderCollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        IconsCollectionFactory $iconsCollectionFactory,
        Data $helper,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = []


    ) {
        $this->attachmentsCollectionFactory = $attachmentsCollectionFactory;
        $this->registry = $context->getRegistry();
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->attachmentAttributesCollection = $attachmentAttributesCollection;
        $this->customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->iconsCollectionFactory = $iconsCollectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $productCollectionFactory, $catalogProductVisibility, $httpContext, $sqlBuilder, $rule, $conditionsHelper, $data);
    }
```

To:

```
public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        ContextHttp $httpContext,
        Builder $sqlBuilder,
        Rule $rule,
        Conditions $conditionsHelper,
        AttachmentAttributesCollection $attachmentAttributesCollection,
        AttachmentsCollectionFactory $attachmentsCollectionFactory,
        SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory,
        OrderCollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        ResourceConnection $resource,
        IconsCollectionFactory $iconsCollectionFactory,
        Data $helper,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
    ) {
        $this->attachmentsCollectionFactory = $attachmentsCollectionFactory;
        $this->registry = $context->getRegistry();
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->attachmentAttributesCollection = $attachmentAttributesCollection;
        $this->customerSessionFactory = $customerSessionFactory;
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->iconsCollectionFactory = $iconsCollectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $productCollectionFactory, $catalogProductVisibility, $httpContext, $sqlBuilder, $rule, $conditionsHelper, $categoryRepository, $data);
    }
```

After this Change please Compile. I thing it will be solved your problem.

Comment: Looks like this worked out, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit function `__construct()` in file `Aitoc/ProductFileAttachments/Block/Product/Attachments.php`.

```
__construct(
....
){
....
parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried and still the same error

Comment: I think your core is wrong. in function `createCollection()`. it's must return product connection but now it return array. because parent class have function same name. And in parent class in function `_beforeToHtml` it call this `$this->setProductCollection($this->createCollection());` so param type is not true

Comment: it's work let me know I will update my answer

Comment: I tried to rename this function but still got the same error. I even tried to remove all functions and left only __constructor()  - again same issue. Probably there is problem with function you said but __constructor seems corrupted too.

Comment: try remove folder generated/code